Exact value of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt2+1}{x\left(8-16\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1{64n^2-1}-\pi\sqrt2-\pi\right)}$, as derived from simple series for pi.
I was reading Euler's E041 ("Concerning the sums of series of reciprocals.") and found some sequences for $\pi$. I believe his derivations are not properly justified. I combined
$$\sqrt2\frac{\pi}4=1+\frac13-\frac15-\frac17+\frac19+\frac1{11}-\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}}{2n+1}\tag{1}$$
and $$\frac{\pi}4=1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\frac19-\frac1{11}+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\tag{2}$$
to get
$$1-(\sqrt2+1)\frac{\pi}8=\frac17-\frac19+\frac1{15}-\frac1{17}+\dots=\frac2{63}+\frac2{255}+\dots=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{64n^2-1}.\tag{3}$$
This has been verified by Wolfram Alpha. However, subtracting one series from the other in order to get $$(\sqrt2-1)\frac{\pi}8=\frac13-\frac15+\frac1{11}-\frac1{13}+\dots=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{16n^2-1}\tag{4}$$ is wrong. It is actually $1-\frac{\pi}4$. This prompts a side question: What justifies $(3)$ that fails in $(4)$? When is messing with infinite sums even justified?
From equation $(3)$, I can formulate an equation for $\pi$:
$$\pi=\frac{8-16\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{64n^2-1}}{\sqrt2+1}.\tag{5}$$
To approximate $\pi$, I take a finite number of terms. If I define $$f(x)=\frac{8-16\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1{64n^2-1}}{\sqrt2+1}\tag{6}$$ then $$E(x)=f(x)-\pi\tag{7}$$ gives the error (and it is positive for all relevant $x$). With the help of Desmos, I found that $\frac1{E(x)}$ is roughly linear (why?), and so $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{xE(x)}$ seems to converge on a value approximately $9.7$. This I have expanded for the title. Therefore I ask whether this truly converges to one value, and if it does, to what value exactly? Since I am just messing around, forgive me if this is straightforward.

Your questions are valid, but I believe they would be better split into two posts (one for infinite series subtraction and the other for the error pattern). This would help users provide focused answers.

$$A_x=\frac{\sqrt2+1}{x\left(8-16\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1{64n^2-1}-\pi\sqrt2-\pi\right)}$$
$$B_x=\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1{64n^2-1}=\sum_{n=1}^x\frac1{(8n-1)(8n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^x\frac{1}{2 (8 n-1)}-\sum_{n=1}^x\frac{1}{2 (8 n+1)}$$ Using harmonic numbers or the digamma function
$$B_x=\frac{1}{16} \left(\psi
   \left(x+\frac{7}{8}\right)-\psi\left(x+\frac{9}{8}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)\right)$$ SImplifying
$$B_x=\frac{1}{16} \left(\psi
   \left(x+\frac{7}{8}\right)-\psi\left(x+\frac{9}{8}\right)+8-\pi\sqrt{3+2 \sqrt{2}} \right)$$
So, the denominator write
$$x\Big( \psi\left(x+\frac{9}{8}\right)-\psi\left(x+\frac{7}{8}\right) \Big)$$ Expanded as series for large $x$, this is
$$\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8 x}+\frac{11}{256x^2}
+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$ Doing long division, its reciprocal is
$$4+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{5}{16x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
So,
$$A_x=4(\sqrt{2}+1)\,\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{2 x}+\frac{5}{64
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)  \Bigg)$$ which gives much more than the limit itself.
For $x=100$ the above truncated series gives $\color{red}{9.705213}96$
